# php soap client issue

Tags: php, soap

I have to develop a php client which connects to a soap webservice server.
With SoapUI, I can test the webservice which is working fine.

But from my php client, I get the following error:

syntax error near << from >>

Here is my php client code:

```
$wsdl = 'http://intrageo.cannes.fr:81/AdresseRecherche/searchByWhereClause?wsdl';

$trace = true;
$exceptions = false;

$xml_array['context'] = '?';
$xml_array['table'] = 'adr_digadr';
$xml_array['colonneARecuperer'] = 'numero';
$xml_array['clauseWere'] = 'nomvoie= \'BOULEVARD COINTET\'';
$xml_array['nbMaxLignes'] = 10;

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' =>  $exceptions));
    $response = $client->getDistinctValue($xml_array);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error!";
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
}

var_dump($response);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use $response=$client->_soapCall("getDistinctValue",$xml_array); instead of $response=$client->getDistinctValue($xml_array)